# How to make an enum conform to Hashable with the API available in Xcode 10?

Tags: swift, xcode10, swift4.2, hashable

In my Swift 4.2.1 code I have this enumeration:

```
enum MyEnum {

    case caseOne(Int)
    case caseTwo(String)
    case caseThree
}
```

It conforms to `Equatable`:

```
extension MyEnum: Equatable {

    static func == (lhs: MyEnum, rhs: MyEnum) -> Bool {

        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.caseOne, .caseOne), (.caseTwo, .caseTwo), (.caseThree, .caseThree):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I need to make it conform to `Hashable`, that's why I added an extension:

```
extension MyEnum: Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int {

        switch self {
        case .caseOne:
            return 1
        case .caseTwo:
            return 2
        case .caseThree:
            return 3
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to migrate to the new API available in Xcode 10. I removed my implementation of `hashValue` and added the implementation of `hash(into:)`:

```
extension MyEnum: Hashable {

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {

        switch self {
        case .caseOne:
            hasher.combine(1)
        case .caseTwo:
            hasher.combine(2)
        case .caseThree:
            hasher.combine(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me if I switched correctly to the new API? I use this test, it prints `true` twice if everything works fine:

```
var testDictionary = [MyEnum: Int]()
testDictionary[.caseOne(100)] = 100
testDictionary[.caseOne(1000)] = 1000
testDictionary[.caseTwo("100")] = 100
testDictionary[.caseTwo("1000")] = 1000
let countCaseOne = testDictionary.reduce(0) {
    if case .caseOne = $1.key {
        return $0 + 1
    }
    return $0
} == 1
print(countCaseOne) // true
let countCaseTwo = testDictionary.reduce(0) {
    if case .caseTwo = $1.key {
        return $0 + 1
    }
    return $0
} == 1
print(countCaseTwo) // true
```

Comment: What do you want to know? It looks correct to me.

Comment: @Sandeep In tutorials I've seen something like ```hasher.combine(self.property)``` in the implementation of ```hash(into:)```. I did not find an example with enum. That's why I want to know if my implementation is correct.

Comment: By the way, you dont have to implement the method yourself. The language does it by itself based on your properties.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use autogenerated `Hashable` conformance, as proposed in the other answer (under condition your type doesn't contains any date of non-`Hashable` types).

But that's what you can do in the general case(autogenerated code would probably look like that too):

```
extension MyEnum: Hashable {

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {

        switch self {
        case .caseOne(let value):
            hasher.combine(value) // combine with associated value, if it's not `Hashable` map it to some `Hashable` type and then combine result
        case .caseTwo(let value):
            hasher.combine(value) // combine with associated value, if it's not `Hashable` map it to some `Hashable` type and then combine result
        case .caseThree:
            // you can `combine` with some `Hashable` constant, but here it's ok just to skip
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why can I skip `combine` for the `.caseThree`?

Comment: Because `hasher` already has some initial state (let's call it `seed`) and then `combine(:)` performs some function with the `hasher` state(`seed` initially)  and then combined value, and result replaces state of the `hasher`. And then state of the `hasher` gets converted to the `hash` function result, which is accessable via `hashValue` property. So, even you won't `combine` at all you will still get a result. Ofc, if you will have multiple `case`s without `associated value` you better to combine it with some `constant`, otherwise hashes of those cases would be identical.

Comment: Check my edited answer please, I added `==` to `MyEnum`.

Comment: Because I don't need to check the associated values.

Comment: @RomanPodymov, well, if you don't need it for hash too, you will be ok using your `hash(into:)` implementation from the answer.

Comment: WARNING: Be really carefull of this; as if `.caseOne` and `.caseTwo` both have an Int as value and are both filled with same contents. They will get the same hashValue; same if you add a caseFour without associated value;

So my advise is always atleast add something extra per hashable case such as an static integer that is unique per case.

Comment: @automaticoo in the question `.caseOne` has Int, but `.caseTwo` **has String**. But, yeah, you better add some "tag" for different case in the Hasher. And I mentioned it in the comment above. For cases without associated value, though. But idea stays the same.

Answer (score 18):

There's no need to implement `Hashable` conformance manually, the compiler can automatically synthesise that for your specific `enum` (where all cases with associated values have a `Hashable` associated value). You just need to declare conformance.

```
enum MyEnum: Hashable {
    case caseOne(Int)
    case caseTwo(String)
    case caseThree
}

// You don't even need to write `: Equatable`, since automatic Hashable conformance takes care of Equatable too, I just left it there for clarity
extension MyEnum: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: MyEnum, rhs: MyEnum) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.caseOne, .caseOne), (.caseTwo, .caseTwo), (.caseThree, .caseThree):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IFF all the associated values of enum are `Hashable` too (or it has none).

Comment: @user28434 yes, that's why I mentioned that for OP's specific enum, but I'll edit my answer to make it more general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I forgot to write that `MyEnum` contains implementation for `==`, check my updated answer please.

Comment: @RomanPodymov that doesn't make a difference, you can still use automatic `Hashable` conformance and overwrite the autosynthetised `==` method. Check my updated answer. Btw are you sure you don't care about the equality of the associated values?

Comment: @DávidPásztor In my case I don't need to check the associated values. And without the implementation of `hash(into:)` the output of my test is `true`/`true`, `true`/`false` or `false`/`true`.